# Why divs are running towards left margin?

Tags: php, css

I am new to css and php, i want to retrieve information from db via php and display it to the user, all working fine but problem is with the UI part [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4k8g.jpg)
and my code is

```php
<?
$result=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
echo "<div class='container'>";
while($row =mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    echo "<div class='row custom1'>";
    echo "<div class='col-sm-12' id='dd' style='border-style:solid; border-width:1px; margin-left:10px; margin-top:20px'><a href='showit.php' class='kk'>";
    echo '<p class="head1">QUESTION:',$row['title'],'</p><p clsss="head2" style="font-size:20px;"></br>Tags:',$row['tags'],'</br>Posted by:',$row['posted'],'</br>Posted On:',$row['postedon'],'</p>';
    echo "</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
?>
```

is there any way to align the divs properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because you're missing the closing `</div>` for the second div and the closing `</a>` in your while loop making a bunch of children of each other, rather than inner nodes of the container parent, use this loop instead:

```
$result=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
echo "<div class='container'>";
while($row =mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    echo "<div class='row custom1'>";
      echo "<div class='col-sm-12' id='dd' style='border-style:solid; border-width:1px; margin-left:10px; margin-top:20px'>";
        echo "<a href='showit.php' class='kk'>";
          echo "<p class=\"head1\">QUESTION:".$row['title']."</p>";
          echo "<p class=\"head2\" style=\"font-size:20px;\">";
            echo "</br>Tags:".$row['tags']."</br>Posted by:".$row['posted']."</br>Posted On:".$row['postedon'];
          echo "</p>";
        echo "</a>";
      echo "</div>"; //col-sm-12
    echo "</div>"; //row custom1
}
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: @user3405916 don't forget to accept the answer, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

By careful you are not closing all tags. I saw that

```
<div class='col-sm-12' id='dd' style='border-style:solid; border-width:1px; margin-left:10px; margin-top:20px'><a href='showit.php' class='kk'>
```

is not closed.

Please go into your browser page and inspect the elements an verify how they are closed.

Comment: he has quite a few unclosed tags